# Moodle configuable reports bar graph not displaying

Tags: moodle

[image]

When I am selected bar graph in reports it showing this image.

I have made a lot of changes but no joy.

The pie and line graphs are working properly only bar graph is not working and am using Moodle configurable reports.

Comment: We need more information: the error codes/messages you have seen and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

check that you have php-gd module installed.
turn debug mode and see errors on screen and on log files.